# all text inputs are blank when validating

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is that how can I get the validation message to appear if there is any blank text input per question?

Here is a fiddle so you can test it: http://jsfiddle.net/cbyJD/87/

Below is the validation() function code:

```
function validation() {

    // only keeping track of the final message
    var alertValidation = "",
        // toggle for showing only one error
        showOnlyOneError = true;

    $("input[data-type='qmark']").each(function(i) {  
        var questions = $(this).attr("data-qnum");
        var marks = parseInt($("[class*=q" + (i+1) + "_ans_text]").text()); 
        var txtinput = $(this).val(); 

        // the message for this question
        var msg = '';

        if (txtinput == '') {
            msg += "\n\u2022 You have not entered in a value in all the Indivdiaul Marks textbox \n";
        }

        if (marks < 0) {
            msg += "\n\u2022 Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n - You Need To Remove " + Math.abs(marks) +  " Marks";   
        } else if (marks > 0) {
            msg += "\n\u2022 Your Total Marks Remaining does not equal 0 \n - You Have " + marks +  " Marks Remaining";   
        }

        // if there is an error for the question, add it to the main message
        if (msg.length) {
            alertValidation += alertValidation.length ? '\n\n' : '';
            alertValidation += "You have errors on Question Number: " + questions + "\n";
            alertValidation += msg;
            // stop if we only care about the first error
            return !showOnlyOneError;
        }
    });

    // show the error messages
    if (alertValidation != "") {
        alert(alertValidation);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is one of those questions I don't know where to begin. I can't seem to find your problem, but it would take me forever to explain why I would do this all different. For example setting unique classes and then doing `$("[class*=q" + (i+1) + "_ans_text]").text();` it's not very practical, classes are meant to be generic, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's your "return after the first error". If you fill in the first box but it has other errors, you will get only those errors - the second box does not get inspected, and you never find out it is empty. The most obvious fix is `showOnlyOneError = false`.

If this is not what you want, then you have to explain the desired semantics of `showOnlyOneError` in more detail.

(Also, a tip: pushing errors into an array then joining them with `"\n\n"` is much more painless than checking each time whether your message string is empty.)

Comment: The reason I need the the `showOnlyOneError = true` is because if multiple questions has errors, it will only show errors for the first question number which contains errors. In you fiddle test it wth `showOnlyOneError = true` and look at the alert, and then text it with `showOnlyOneError = false`, you can see it duplicates the error message for blank text input